# What must type be for createDateFrame(data: dateFrameLike) parameter?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following code to create a pyspark DataFrame:

```py
from typing import List, Dict, Any
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import (
    FloatType,
    IntegerType,
    StringType,
    StructField,
    StructType,
)

def purchases_schema() -> StructType:
    return StructType(
        [
            StructField("Customer", StringType(), True),
            StructField("Store", StringType(), True),
            StructField("Product", StringType(), True),
            StructField("Quantity", IntegerType(), True),
            StructField("Basket", StringType(), True),
            StructField("GrossSpend", FloatType(), True),
        ]
    )

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
transactions = [
    {
        "Customer": "Leia",
        "Store": "Hammersmith",
        "Basket": "basket1",
        "items": [
            {"Product": "Cheddar", "Quantity": 2, "GrossSpend": 2.50},
            {"Product": "Grapes", "Quantity": 1, "GrossSpend": 3.00},
        ],
    },
    {
        "Customer": "Luke",
        "Store": "Ealing",
        "Basket": "basket2",
        "items": [
            {
                "Product": "Custard",
                "Quantity": 1,
                "GrossSpend": 3.00,
            }
        ],
    },
]
flattened_transactions: List[Dict[str, Any]] = [
    {
        "Customer": d["Customer"],
        "Store": d["Store"],
        "Basket": d["Basket"],
        **d2,
    }
    for d in transactions
    for d2 in d["items"]
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(flattened_transactions, schema=purchases_schema())
print(df.collect())
```

It works fine, here is the output:

```bash
➜ python script.py
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
22/11/29 10:52:19 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
[Row(Timestamp=None, Customer='Leia', Store='Hammersmith', Channel=None, Product='Cheddar', Quantity=2, Basket='basket1', GrossSpend=2.5), Row(Timestamp=None, Customer='Leia', Store='Hammersmith', Channel=None, Product='Grapes', Quantity=1, Basket='basket1', GrossSpend=3.0), Row(Timestamp=None, Customer='Luke', Store='Ealing', Channel=None, Product='Custard', Quantity=1, Basket='basket2', GrossSpend=3.0)]
```

What bothers me is that my IDE is complaining about the list passed to `createDataFrame`'s `data` parameter:

> Argument of type "list[Dict[str, Any]]" cannot be assigned to parameter "data" of type "DataFrameLike" in function "createDataFrame"n  "list[Dict[str, Any]]" is incompatible with "DataFrameLike"

[image: screenshot of error in IDE]

Given that the code runs successfully I'm slightly surprised about this complaint from the IDE. Can someone suggest how I can solve this problem (without simply sticking `# type: ignore` on the end of the line)

Comment: Instead of using `List[Dict[str, Any]]` try `Iterable[Dict[str, Any]]`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It didn't help unfortunately, I still have the same problem.